# What is the maximum age limit for getting a pilot licence?

Tags: flight-training

Can I do pilot training courses even after age 26 ?

Comment: Please consider specifying which country and/or legislation you are interested in, answers might vary and making a comprehensive list for all world's country might be too much for the SE format.

Comment: Please also provide more information on what type of license? ATPL / CPL / PPL / SPL ...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there are no maximum age restrictions on getting a pilots license anywhere in the world. Many countries have a **minimum** age restriction for getting a license, that usually does not prevent pilot training from taking place. 26 is fine, in fact 76 is fine as long as you pass whatever medical is required.

Comment: there are many glider pilots over 80

Comment: It should be noted that it may be more difficult for older pilots to pass the medical exam

Comment: Absolutely, that's probably one reason that there is no upper age limit. The system relies on the medical exam to ensure pilots are fit to fly.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on @GdD's answer, a number of aeronautical regulatory bodies, including the FAA, do not specify a maximum age for flight training or executing the privileges of Pilot-In-Command *under most circumstances*; as long as you hold a valid medical, you're in the clear.

That said, your individual circumstances may be different. There are some exceptions to this even in the civilian world, such as maximum age limits when flying for certain airlines (such as the age 65 rule for Part 121 operations in the US). If you're in a part of the world where airlines offer cadet programs and such, they may also impose maximum age limits for applicants.

If you're interested in military flying, the armed services may also have additional restrictions on maximum age for flight training; the USAF for example, had the age of 26 as the upper bound for anyone applying for a pilot slot about 5-6 years ago, and armed forces the world over have similar restrictions in place.

Edit:

Thanks to @SSumner for providing a [link](http://usmilitary.about.com/od/joiningthemilitary/l/blpilotage.htm) with the current age limits for US military pilot training.

Comment: For the US military you can see [these ages](http://usmilitary.about.com/od/joiningthemilitary/l/blpilotage.htm) - I think it's actually been longer than 5-6 years since the AF raised the limit to 28.5. And there are waivers for this - I went through with a guy who was about 34, and I know of at least one who was about 38 going through pilot training

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'd heard about the age 26 limit from a former flight instructor of mine who was coming up on it and she was really happy that she was able to get her slot in time to begin UPT before that happened. Then again, she did get her pilot slot thru the Alabama ANG, so who knows?

Comment: It's certainly possible that  a guard unit could set a lower age for some reason. Active duty and guard can be very different in some areas

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you specify if you are getting the license to fly private or commercially. For private there is no age restriction if you pass your medical, as is the same for commercial. However as mentioned some airlines may prevent you from flying after a certain time. That all being said [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJk9Skxyi84) brings up some good points about starting training later in life (in your 30's). It takes a lot of hours to become a commercial pilot and the later you start training the later you enter the workforce (as with any job). I would think 26 is perfectly fine. Im getting my Private Pilot and started at 23. There are plenty of people at the flight school well over 50 starting their training as well.