# What are the requirements to get a private pilot's license in Indonesia?

Tags: student-pilot, indonesia

I am interested to get license to pilot small civil aircraft (up to max. 4 passengers including the pilot him/herself). I read [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15116/what-is-the-maximum-age-limit-for-getting-a-pilot-licence) that there is no age limitation to get the license as long pass the medical check.

What is the required knowledge to get the license? Is anyone here has the shareable pilot training and testing material?

Edit:
I am and Indonesian and stay in Indonesia. The license I want to get is for private slow aircraft such as Cessna which the speed should not more than 300km/h. Passengers are family members or friends, not commercial.

Comment: It helps just a tad if we know what country you're asking about.

Comment: I have added more info to get clearer intention. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Indonesian air regulations](http://hubud.dephub.go.id/?en/dsku/index/filter:tahun,0;bulan,0;category,1) include *[CASR 61 Licensing of Pilots & Flight Instructors](http://hubud.dephub.go.id/?en/dsku/download/8438)*, which has all the detailed requirements for getting a Student license (subpart C) and then a Private license (subpart D). To get a more 'friendly' overview of what they really mean, I would look for a local flight school that can explain the practical steps.

Interestingly, the Indonesian regulations appear to be very closely based on the US ones.